# Merging all the "Is this url seo friendly" questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I know when I come across a duplicate question, I'm supposed to flag it (and I do.) However, there seriously must be 50 "Which of these urls is the most SEO friendly" questions all across the Stack Exchange. I went over my flagging limit on the ole' overflow, flagging questions that belong here on Webmasters and I must have come across 15 of these questions.

Also, since there are so many duplicates... which do we choose to be the question that all these should be marked as a duplicate of:

The first one or the most popular, well written one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw that, and thank you.

However, do make sure you only flag questions that have sufficient quality -- questions that are *worthy* of migration. Either because

- they are great questions
- they have great answers

The low quality off-topic questions really should just remain on Stack Overflow and be deleted, honestly, unless they have great answers.

So don't hesitate to flag low quality on those, while you're finding the good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'd pick the most well written one, and make it a community wiki, and then bring in all the other variations into the question text (or ask others to).